# Understanding Ruby match method of Regexp class

Tags: ruby, regex

I was reading about the `match` method in `ruby`, I understood most of the example given at [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Regexp.html)

But I am failing to understand, why is:

```
/[0-9a-f]/.match('9f')
=> #<MatchData "9">
```

And not:

```
=> #<MatchData "9f">
```

I might be missing some basic understanding of Regex, so bear with me.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're asking it to match a single character of class 0-9 or a-f.

If you want to match multiple use a plus or an asterisk after the character classes e.g. `/[0-9a-f]+/.match('9f')`

It's all [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info).